# Get incoming call event

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

How can we register to listen for an incoming call event in Windows 10 UWP on a mobile device ?

I tried [Windows Call Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CallerID) but it works only for unknown dialers. I've also tried to register the sample with different `PhoneTriggerType` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This would be more useful, if you showed the code you tried. Stating that you tried something else doesn't serve as a good base.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried Windows Call Sample but it works only for unknown dialers. I've also tried to register the sample with different PhoneTriggerType but that doesn't seem to work.

If you want to listen for any incoming call event. You can use [PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.callstatechanged.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event like below:

```
PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged += (o, args) =>
{
       If(PhoneCallManager.IsCallIncoming)
       {
           // do your things
       } 
};
```

And also don't forget to make your app the default Phone Call APP on your device.

Comment: Thank you ! This is great, but how can we monitor this in the background ? Is there any background trigger that can be registered in a BackgroundTaskBuilder ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such trigger for incoming call. You can refer to [PhoneTriggerType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.background.phonetriggertype?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It lists all the phonecall trigger type. You can use `CallHistoryChanged` trigger, but it triggers the backgroundTask after the phoneCall not before the phoneCall. So it is not possible to monitor this in background.

Comment: Actually there was a type in AccessoryManager but as far as I know this API will become obsolete and we need to migrate to a new API ...